# compare first property of two object and merge

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

i have one question for compate two object property i have two object with different value i want to compare object and if first property in both object then change property value 
this is my object

1)

```
obj1 = {A: 1001, B: 3147020, C: 30},
{A: 1002, B: 3147021, C: 30},
{A: 1003, B: 3147022, C: 30};
```

2)

```
obj2 = {A: 1001, B: 3147020, C: 30},
{A: 1002, B: 3147021, C: 30},
{A: 1004, B: 3147022, C: 30};
```

when i compare if i find same value A in both object so change obj1 B value to obj2 B value 
and if you have any ides for check in both object like obj1 all A value not same to obj2 all Value so please help me for this question

Answer (score 0):

Those are not objects.

This is an object:

```
obj1 = {A: 1001, B: 3147020, C: 30};
```

This is an array

```
arr1 = ['Hello', 'World', '!'];
```

And you can make an array of objects, example:

```
items = [{A: 1001, B: 3147020, C: 30},
  {A: 1002, B: 3147021, C: 30},
  {A: 1003, B: 3147022, C: 30}];
```

So, what exactly is your question?  Could you rephrase?

Comment: my question is for object